How to create subnetworks with sfnetworks in R
I would like to create subnetworks from a spatial network:
 library(sfnetworks)
 library(sf)
 library(tidygraph)
 library(igraph)


  net = as_sfnetwork(roxel, directed = FALSE) %>%
     st_transform(3035)

Let's say I have a list of points (with ID or geometries) that could be considered as borders of the subnetworks. How divide the network?  How to plot in different colors the edges of the new subnetworks?
 points = st_geometry(net, "nodes")[sample(1:701,100)]
 plot(net)
 plot(points, col = "red", add = TRUE)

I have seen the functions to_spatial_subdivision and to_spatial_subset but not sure they are appropriate in my case
https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/sfn05_morphers.html
Other example :  I  have a graph g
 g <- make_graph(edges = c(1, 2, 1, 8, 2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8), n 
    = 8, directed = FALSE)
 plot(g)
 # if borders are nodes 1 and 7  , I want two graphs g1 and g2
 g1 <- delete_edges(g, get.edge.ids(g, c(1, 8, 7, 8)))
 plot(g1) #without vertices id 8

Update :
 #borders 1 and 7
#desired output:
 plot(g, edge.color = c("red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "red", "blue"))

  #borders 3  and 8
  #desired output:
  plot(g, edge.color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", 
    "red", "red", "red"))

 #borders 3,  4  and 8
 #desired output:
 plot(g, edge.color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "red", 
     "red", "red", "red"))
 


Hi Felipe! Did you check the vignette on spatial joins?

Yes, but in my case the delimitations are nodes of the network. I completed my question with an igraph example

Regarding your igraph example, how do you decide which adjacent edge should be removed? When you consider nodes 1 & 7 as borders (which should remain in one of those networks?), what's the logic behind eliminating edges 1-8 & 7-8 instead of  1-2 & 7-6?

I dont want to remove any edges or nodes actually (it was just to illustrate), I just want to divide in two subnetworks, 1-8 & 7-8 from one side, in one colour; 1-2 & 7-6 and all other edges from the other side in another colour

Do you have the coordinates o the nodes that should define the subnetworks or just their ID? Could you provide a more precise example of the desired output?

Let's say, it is a water network and some of the nodes are closed valves, I would like to color the different part of the network, into subareas. I am interested in both case agila ;)  node ID first , (and coordinates in  second). The desired output is the original network with colors for each zones, I will try to make an example manually
